# How to minimize the number of CSS classes created?

Tags: css, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net webforms project. I am pretty comfortable with CSS and could write complex styling with it. The problem I am facing is how to minimize the number of classes created or efficiently reuse existing ones. For example each page requires several  divs to be displayed at certain place and pretty soon I will be creating too many classes for different pages. I could have avoided this by using bootstrap, but bootstrap is not allowed for my project. The following is a sample CSS I had to use for a small section one one page.

```
 <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 300px; padding-bottom: 50px; " ><asp:button id="btnAssociae" ToolTip="Associate" runat="server" Text="Associate" onclick="btnAssociate_Click"></asp:button></div>
    <div style="margin-left: 65px; border-bottom: 1px solid"></div>
    <div style="padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 60px; " ><span style="padding-right: 90px">Delete</span><asp:button id="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" onclick="btnDelete_Click"></asp:button>
    </div>
```

probably one idea will be to use percentages instead of px. Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Note: The enclosed code sample shows inline CSS, which I will eventually convert into classes.

Comment: So just add a class to the body, that will identify how the page should be styled, and go on from there. For example, class home, will be for the homepage; class about, will be for the info/about page; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try BEM methodology. For example here is some description: http://getbem.com/
I'm working with it day by day and stylesheets are much easier to maintain.

Some basics good practics:
- Make general classes, like: .container with some default paddings/margins for all sections on pages

- Helpers - classess like 'align-left' or 'text-white' with only one parametr so you can make different styles just by adding classes not by creating new ones
- Try Sass/LESS - creating code with them are MUCH easier than in 'normal' css. You can also split style into smaller files and name it "buttons" where are classes only for buttons and so on
- Using pixels are acceptable but 'em' or 'rem' are somehow better. Percents can be tricky, especially for RWD
- Flexbox is a really great tool for vertical/horizontal div positioning

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I agree with Ula. BEM is great for shrinking the number of classes. Also, just because bootstrap isn't allowed on your project doesn't mean you can't adopt their method and build something yourself. Bootstrap is just a library of utility classes you can install, why not create a separate stylesheet called tools.css and define some utility classes you can reuse throughout the whole project.

Also, I can't agree more with using SASS to neaten things up. If you feel like you're ready to learn something new, it's a great tool for writing clean styles. https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-sass/ -> This is a great resource for learning.